# Is a COM Add-In the same as Office Addin project in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, com, outlook, outlook-addin

I am a newbie to Microsoft Office Application development and I need to create a COM add-in for Microsoft Office and so far, the only viable sources which point to a COM add-in is : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa140126

I am guessing the `Office > 2010 > Outlook Add-In` project is `VSTO` and not COM.

If so,what would be the best way to get started with developing an actual COM Add In? As in environment(Visual Studio if possible) and resources. I am assuming COM is the way to go since `VSTO` uses a wrapper which simplifies things and doesn't give the developer as much control as COM.

Comment: What do you mean with VSTO "doesn't give the developer as much control as COM"? With both VSTO and COM you get access to the underlying object model of Outlook, Word, etc. Anyhow, if you want to create a COM add-in you should look for the "Shared Add-in" project template in VS.

Comment: So, is there an actual advantage/disadvantage of using one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

> I am guessing the Office > 2010 > Outlook Add-In project is VSTO and not COM.

Not exactly. Yes, Visual Studio templates belong to VSTO. But all kind of Office add-ins are based on the [IDTExtensibility2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.idtextensibility2.aspx) interface, i.e. based on the COM technology. The interface hosts the event notifications that occur to add-ins, such as when they are loaded, unloaded, updated, and so forth. Well-known implementations are VSTO and Add-in Express.

VSTO provides a convinient implementation of the IDTExtensibility interface, Ribbon designers, loader (to load your add-in into a separate AppDomain) etc.

It is up to you which way is to choose, but latest versions of Visual Studio don't provide templates for creating shared (a raw IDTExtensibility implementation) add-ins. You need to handle all operations on your own.